# Pandas- Filling in missing data with np.where() and iterrow()..but it's too slow please tell me how to improve

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, rolling-computation

I'm trying to fill missing data values in a pandas dataframe based on date.

Approximate values range from 54.5 to 71.5.
When on/off is 1, the value increases, and when on/off is 0, the value decreases.

```
>> before (example)
day_time        value  on/off
2020-03-01 0:05 71.35    0
2020-03-01 0:06 68.425   0
2020-03-01 0:07 66.1     0
2020-03-01 0:08 64.125   0
2020-03-01 0:09 58.9     0
2020-03-01 0:10 56.075   0
2020-03-01 0:11 54.35    0
2020-03-01 0:12 57.025   1
2020-03-01 0:13 59.35    1
2020-03-01 0:14 63.2     1
2020-03-01 0:15 65.375   1
2020-03-01 0:16 66.35    1
2020-03-01 0:17 67.25    1
2020-03-01 0:18 70.05    1
2020-03-01 0:19 NaN      NaN
2020-03-01 0:20 NaN      NaN
2020-03-01 0:21 NaN      NaN
2020-03-01 0:22 NaN      NaN
2020-03-01 0:23 NaN      NaN
2020-03-01 0:24 NaN      NaN
2020-03-01 0:25 NaN      NaN
2020-03-01 0:26 NaN      NaN
2020-03-01 0:27 NaN      NaN
2020-03-01 0:28 NaN      NaN
2020-03-01 0:29 NaN      NaN
2020-03-01 0:30 NaN      NaN
2020-03-01 0:31 NaN      NaN
2020-03-01 0:32 65.475   1
2020-03-01 0:33 65.475   1
2020-03-01 0:34 65.525   0
```

I calculate the value while the missing value occurs,
I want to fill it.

I want to calculate it so that it can increase or decrease repeatedly in the range of 71.5~54.5 by the amount of change (average) of the value just before the missing value occurs.

```
>> after (example)
day_time        value  on/off
2020-03-01 0:05 71.35    0
2020-03-01 0:06 68.425   0
2020-03-01 0:07 66.1     0
2020-03-01 0:08 64.125   0
2020-03-01 0:09 58.9     0
2020-03-01 0:10 56.075   0
2020-03-01 0:11 54.35    0
2020-03-01 0:12 57.025   1
2020-03-01 0:13 59.35    1
2020-03-01 0:14 63.2     1
2020-03-01 0:15 65.375   1
2020-03-01 0:16 66.35    1
2020-03-01 0:17 67.25    1
2020-03-01 0:18 70.05    1
2020-03-01 0:19 68.05    0
2020-03-01 0:20 67.35    0
2020-03-01 0:21 65.21    0
2020-03-01 0:22 63.275   0
2020-03-01 0:23 65.225   0
2020-03-01 0:24 63.65    0
2020-03-01 0:25 61.45    0
2020-03-01 0:26 58.45    0
2020-03-01 0:27 56.275   0
2020-03-01 0:28 55.475   0
2020-03-01 0:29 54.3     0
2020-03-01 0:30 57.7     1
2020-03-01 0:31 59.5     1
2020-03-01 0:32 61.4     1
2020-03-01 0:33 63.5     1
2020-03-01 0:34 65.525   1
```

I try below,,

```
for i in result.iterrows():
  result['pump'] = np.where(pd.isnull(result.pump), np.where((result.pump.shift(1) == 0) & (result.g_hight.shift(1) > 54), 0, result.pump), result.pump)
  result['pump'] = np.where(pd.isnull(result.pump), np.where((result.pump.shift(1) == 0) & (result.g_hight.shift(1) < 72), 1, result.pump), result.pump)
  result['pump'] = np.where(pd.isnull(result.pump), np.where((result.pump.shift(1) == 1) & (result.g_hight.shift(1) < 72), 1, result.pump), result.pump)
  result['pump'] = np.where(pd.isnull(result.pump), np.where((result.pump.shift(1) == 1) & (result.g_hight.shift(1) > 54), 0, result.pump), result.pump)

  value_ON = result['g_hight'].shift(1) - result['fi_usage'].shift(1) + 0.2503
  value_OFF = (result['g_hight'].shift(1) - result['fi_usage'].shift(1))
  result['g_hight'] = np.where((pd.isnull(result.g_hight)) & (pd.notna(result.pump)), np.where(result.pump == 0, value_OFF, value_ON), result.g_hight)
result.to_csv('result_1.csv', index = False)
```

It is working but.. too late ..
how to improve this process??

Answer (score 1):

The problem is somewhat vague and may require significant work, so I just outline the plan below.

I would start from a simple model like

```
value = a sin(bx + c) + d
```

Why sine? Because it is periodic, fluctuates between growth and decay, and is a good simple model to start from.

I suggest estimating `b` first. It is a value of the full cycle. How long does it take to reach maximum again? Say, `t` time. Then, `b = 2 * pi / t`.

Once `b` is determined, I recommend the following trick:

```
value = a sin(bx + c) + d = A sin(bx) + B cos(bx) + C
```

If we know `b`, then we know `sin(bx)` and `cos(bx)`, and, therefore, all we need to know is `A`, `B`, and `C`. They can be found using regression on the known values. Finally, apply the formula to estimate the missing values.